# It is possible use links that will choose a route inside of a ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

All samples of `ng-view` directive shows that it must being used like follows

```
<div class="header">
    <a href="/view/1"></a>
    <a href="/view/2"></a>
    <a href="/view/3"></a>
</div>
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

I think a little while taking a shower and the doubt below comes to play with the need of lazily load all content with help of resolves in `ng-view` plus `ng-switch` and `ng-include`. Something new, without an AMD solution to templating like requirejs!text plugin and angularjs providers. The idea is change the subview thru the links inside of `ngView`. The view template will being something like that:

```
<div>
    <a href="#\item-profile\1">Item Profile</a>
    <a href="#\status\2">status</a>
    <a href="#\status\3">View1</a>
</div>
<div ng-switch="view">
    <div ng-switch-when="item-profile">
        <div ng-include="'item-profile.html'">
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="status">
        <div ng-include="'status.html'">
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-switch="subView">
    <div ng-switch-when="1">
        <div ng-include="'sub-view1.html'">
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="2">
        <div ng-include="'sub-view2.html'">
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="3">
        <div ng-include="'sub-view3.html'">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the index.html will looks like:

```
<body>
    <ng-view></ngview>
</body>
```

And the route configuration:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).config([
    '$routeProvider',
    function (rp){
        rp.when('/:view/:subView', {
            template: 'view.html',
            controller: [
                '$scope',
                '$route',
                function (s, r) {
                    s.subView = r.params.subView;
                    s.view = r.params.view;
                }
            ]
        });
    }
]);
```

But for some reason this does not work, follow the code on [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/d9zN2p6MBRFV063smV51)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), specifically [its nested/sub-views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views) and [named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views).

Comment: not at all, What i really need is a way to lazily load the navigation header because it is built accordingly the data that was fetched from backend.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been a bit clearer, I meant that ui-router's sub and named views as a replacement for your ng-switches, they are easier to work with and way more versatile. I'll make you a plunker tomorrow if I have time.

Comment: Ok I´m test with it, is good, and resolves with lazily load the navheader!